how to make cancel button to cancel or stop task async in my proxy checker code
I don't know how to cancel this
namespace WindowsFormsApplication7
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        public async Task testProxy(string ip, int port)
        {
            bool OK = false;
            try
            {
                WebClient wc = new WebClient();
                wc.Proxy = new WebProxy(ip, port);
                await wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync(new Uri("http://google.com/ncr"));
                OK = true;
                addgood();
                richTextBox2.Text += ip + ":" + port + "\n";
            }
            catch { }
        }
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        private void bunifuFlatButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "TXT Files | *.txt";
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string fileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                proxy_list.Text = File.ReadAllText(@fileName);
                proxy_list.Refresh();
            }
        }
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        private void start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  //start checker
        {
            if (proxy_list.Lines.Length < 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Proxy list is Vide");
            }
            else
            {
                var asyncTasks = new Task[proxy_list.Lines.Length];
                for (int i = 0; i < proxy_list.Lines.Length; i++)
                {
                    var tab = proxy_list.Lines[i].Split(':');
                    asyncTasks[i] = testProxy(tab[0], int.Parse(tab[1]));
                }
                Task.WaitAll(asyncTasks);
            }
        }
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     private void cancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //stop checker
     {

         //cancel here

     }

    }
}


You need to create a CancellationTokenSource and pass its Token to the WebClient invocation and cancel it in the button event handler.

thanks for reply please you can give me example

Given the context you have presented and given the official Microsoft documentation on DownloadStringTaskAsync, you need to use CancellationTokenSource, but the function cannot receive a second parameter to use as a cancellation token, a possible solution is to develop your own DownloadString askAsync() here I show you an example that works for me:
public static class WebClientExtensions {

    public static Task<string> DownloadStringTaskAsync(this WebClient webClient, string address, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
        cancellationToken.Register(() => webClient.CancelAsync());

        webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += (sender, e) => {
            if (e.Cancelled) {
                tcs.TrySetCanceled();
            } else if (e.Error != null) {
                tcs.TrySetException(e.Error);
            } else {
                tcs.TrySetResult(e.Result);
            }
        };

        webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(address));
        return tcs.Task;
    }
}

Now with your own developed DownloadStringTaskAsync you can make use of the token as I show you below:
private CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource;

public async Task testProxy(string ip, int port, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
    try {
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.Proxy = new WebProxy(ip, port);
        await wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync("http://google.com/ncr", cancellationToken);
    } catch (OperationCanceledException) {
        // Task cancelled, handle as needed
        MessageBox.Show("WORK!");
    }
}

If anyone else encounters this problem, here is the complete code that worked for me:
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    private TextBox proxy_list;
    private Button startButton;
    private Button cancelButton;

    private CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource;

    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponents();
    }

    private void InitializeComponents() {
        this.proxy_list = new TextBox();
        this.startButton = new Button();
        this.cancelButton = new Button();
        proxy_list.Text = "192.168.1.1:8080\n" +
              "192.168.1.2:8080\n" +
              "192.168.1.3:8080";

        // proxy_list
        this.proxy_list.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
        this.proxy_list.Multiline = true;
        this.proxy_list.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(260, 300);
        this.Controls.Add(this.proxy_list);

        // startButton
        this.startButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 318);
        this.startButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 30);
        this.startButton.Text = "Start";
        this.startButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.startButton_Click);
        this.Controls.Add(this.startButton);

        // cancelButton
        this.cancelButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(118, 318);
        this.cancelButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 30);
        this.cancelButton.Text = "Cancel";
        this.cancelButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.cancel_Click);
        this.Controls.Add(this.cancelButton);
    }

    public async Task testProxy(string ip, int port, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
        try {
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            wc.Proxy = new WebProxy(ip, port);
            await wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync("http://google.com/ncr", cancellationToken);
        } catch (OperationCanceledException) {
            // Task cancelled, handle as needed
            MessageBox.Show("WORK!");
        }
    }

    private async void startButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (proxy_list.Lines.Length < 1) {
            MessageBox.Show("Proxy list is empty");
        } else {
            cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var cancellationToken = cancellationTokenSource.Token;
            foreach (var line in proxy_list.Lines) {
                var tab = line.Split(':');
                if (tab.Length == 2 && int.TryParse(tab[1], out int port)) {
                    await testProxy(tab[0], port, cancellationToken);
                } else {
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid proxy format: " + line);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void cancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        cancellationTokenSource?.Cancel();
    }
}

public static class WebClientExtensions {

    public static Task<string> DownloadStringTaskAsync(this WebClient webClient, string address, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
        cancellationToken.Register(() => webClient.CancelAsync());

        webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += (sender, e) => {
            if (e.Cancelled) {
                tcs.TrySetCanceled();
            } else if (e.Error != null) {
                tcs.TrySetException(e.Error);
            } else {
                tcs.TrySetResult(e.Result);
            }
        };

        webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(address));
        return tcs.Task;
    }
}

